# How to see how much storage is used per app on OS X?

Tags: macos, storage

I was wondering if there is a way to check how much space is used for each app that's installed on your mac. When you click on the Apple logo left on top, then "About this mac" you can see at the tab "Storage" the total amount of pictures, programs, other, movies and music. But it would be nice if I can check per app how much space the take on my mac. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not afraid of using `Terminal.app`, you can run

```
sudo du -sh /Applications/* /Applications/Utilities/*
```

to get the size of each application.

Comment: the "-sh" switch is broken down into "s" which gives you summary stats (Display an entry for reach specified file) and "h" which gives you human readable output.  Of course you could look these switches up yourself by reading "man du".

Answer (score 1):

The full answer is not easily. The short answer is for most apps, you can ignore the settings, preferences and other files stored outside of the Application binary and can open /Applications in Finder and enable calculate all folder sizes:

Open a finder window:

- Command + Shift + A - go to applications
- Command + 2 - show the list view
- Command + J - pull up that folder's view options
- Select the **Calculate all sizes** control

The system will then add up all the storage for each app and you can click on the size column to sort it. A general purpose tool like Daisy Disk or What Size might also help you keep tabs on the files an application might store in /Library since apps like Garage band or Logic Pro can download significant amount of sound loops and instruments - but they usually tell you explicitly before those downloads start.